# Why does a running ping process keep working during an internet outage, but restarting ping doesn't?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ping, cable-modem

For the last few months, I'm struggling with regular internet outages, affecting all devices on my local network, forcing me to power cycling my cable modem.
Today I noticed that I can reproduce this issue - or a similar one with the same symptoms - by installing a game with Blizzard's Battle.net.

It's not only about saturating my bandwidth, since

- the download itself also stops,
- it's also happening when limiting the download speed,
- and it doesn't resolve itself automatically when pausing the download - only restarting the modem helps.

To see exactly when my internet connection fails, I'm running a simple `ping 8.8.8.8` on a separate Linux notebook (I'm using Arch btw) connected to the same network - but I'm still able to continue pinging, even when my internet fails!
Only when stopping the running *ping*, and restarting it, I'm not getting any responses anymore.

I'm a bit baffled by this behaviour.
I also tried running `ping 8.8.8.8` and `watch -n1 ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` side by side - while the continually running *ping* process keeps working, the *ping* process regularly restarted by *watch* fails as soon as my internet goes down.

How is this possible?
It apparently seems like "active ping sessions" aren't affected by my outage. But with ping using ICMP on layer 3, I don't get why there is a difference between keeping *ping* running, in contrast to doing a fresh start.

After seeing that Battle.net downloads also cause this issue, I immediatley suspected something related to too many P2P connections clogging my router. But neither am I sure if Battle.net actually uses P2P, nor am I seeing anything suspicious on my router regarding active connections (~3,000 to 4,000 connections out of 15,360 max), memory usage or therelike.

Unfortunately, I can't really look at metrics from my cable modem, as my ISP doesn't provide a proper interface - which is also why I'm running it in bridge mode.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

**Edit**: I had a look at the ICMP messages using Wireshark:
the only noticable difference between the ICMP echo requests getting a response and those that don't:

- the ICMP identifier is tied to the process; requests from the running *ping* have the same id, requests from the restarting ping get a new one
- the sequence number increases for every request sent by the running *ping*, but is set to 1 for the restarting one

That's very much expected behaviour, and doesn't really help me any further - after all, why would this cause the requests to get treated differently?

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on how to diagnose this any further, or for better ideas to reproduce an outage than deleting and downloading Diablo IV again!

Comment: In `iptables`-speak, this can happen if "_allow_" rules are dropped (either specific or generic) while established/related rule(s) persist... In this situation, any new connection would fail, but any existing connection would continue working (including sequential pings). You might find that Blizzard's software downloads chunks, and it get's "stuck" when starting the next chunk. As to why you're seeing these symptoms or what is responsible, I cannot say... It could be equipment owned by your or your ISP - have you swapped what you can?

Comment: @Attie thanks for the comment! I haven't swapped my cable modem, since I would either get the same underpowered model if I explicitly request so, or the newer default one which might have more resources, but has less functionality and doesn't support my use cases (bridge mode, or at least port forwarding...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How is this possible? It apparently seems like "active ping sessions" aren't affected by my outage. But with ping using ICMP on layer 3, I don't get why there is a difference between keeping ping running, in contrast to doing a fresh start.

Even for protocols that don't have explicit state, like UDP and ICMP Echo, your router still needs to keep its own state for its firewall and NAT functions. (For example, it keeps track of NAT mappings to know which internal host to return the Echo Reply packets to.) For such protocols, any first packet that you send establishes the state; a timeout after inactivity causes it to be removed.

Just like with TCP, the state table remembers the source-destination ports of a UDP packet flow, or the singular "request ID" of an ICMP Echo flow. Although ICMP doesn't have port numbers, Echo requests have an ID that serves the same purpose of distinguishing flows from one another. (If you look at a packet capture in Wireshark you'll see this.) Meaning, each new `ping` invocation causes a new state entry to be added.

*(For a practical example: If you do `conntrack -L` you can see the states tracked by your computer's iptables/nftables firewall, which is basically the same as what most home routers use internally. Note the `id` field of ICMP Echo states.)*

So from your problem description, it indeed sounds like the router's state table fills up from too many "connections" and its firmware was configured to stop accepting new states, instead of letting them push out old ones. (To be fair, I *think* that's the default behavior of Linux conntrack?)

It might also be that the problematic router has a bug that prevents it from ever *clearing* states, and its memory just fills up until a reboot; especially if the router offloads NAT to hardware acceleration and if said offload has broken state removal. (I would be entirely unsurprised if that was the case and the ISP just programmed it to reboot once a week, which would be "good enough" for casual users.)

Battle.net doesn't use P2P these days, it's just HTTP from a CDN (though it used to be BitTorrent-based long ago), but it *does* establish a relatively large amount of parallel HTTP downloads and can certainly contribute to the problem.

Finally, as mentioned in the comments, it's *possible* (though I'm not sure if likely) that your router's firewall loses all of the filter and/or NAT rules. This would make sense for a Linux-based device – indeed iptables automatically processes NAT for existing states, so if the outgoing SNAT or MASQUERADE rule gets removed for some reason, it'll prevent new connections from being made but existing ones will continue to work (they'll continue to be NATed according to information already stored in the state).

---

If you find no way to solve it, a VPN would likely be a workaround – the entire VPN tunnel counts as just one state as far as your router can see it.

Comment: A state table filling up is a very good lead, thank you! I'm pretty sure the issue is with the ISP provided cable modem, a Compal CH7465MT *Connect box* - it's running in bridge mode because I suspected it to be too weak to even do reliable DHCP. Would every new state show up both in my modem and my router (an Archer A7 running OpenWrt)?
In OpenWrt, I'm never seeing >5k or >30% active connections, so I thought the modem should be able to handle that as well; but I'm also not entirely sure if *active connections* is the same as *state table size* in OpenWrt.

Comment: Each router along the way that does NAT and/or firewalling will track the states, so if you have two layers of NAT then it'll show up on both – but if the modem is in bridge mode, it shouldn't track states at all. I'm not sure about what the UI reports, but if you have OpenWRT you can ssh to it and a) check `conntrack`, b) check `dmesg` (if I remember correctly it'll complain there if the state table reaches its limits), c) try flushing it using the conntrack command and see if it restores everything.

Comment: Though if it's a *cable* modem, or an LTE modem, those can't have true "bridge" mode since there's no Ethernet on the WAN side (so they still do routing and just pass through the IP address), and it *could* be that the "bridge mode" modem still does the same.

Comment: Thanks, I'll tear it down again and have a look as soon as my fiancée goes to bed ;) But iirc, restarting the router didn't do much in the past, which is also why I'm suspecting the modem rather than the router. `a timeout after inactivity causes it to be removed` - this will very much depend on the hardware or my ISP's configuration of the modem, but what are typical timeouts for state entries to be removed? Would you expect minutes, hours or days? Had to restart the modem a couple of times after coming home from vacation or longer weekends, so doesn't feel like it's "self healing".

Comment: For implicit states (UDP and such), it's usually minutes; 120 seconds is typical. See `sysctl net.netfilter | grep udp_timeout` for Linux/OpenWRT. (For protocols that have explicit setup (TCP) the recommended idle timeout is in days, but most routers will still only do hours at most (if not minutes) to conserve RAM.)

Comment: Though, it might not necessarily be regular "fill up", especially when it comes to highly specialized firmware (like cable modems). For example, at one point we used to run pfSense (FreeBSD-based) on Hyper-V as our router, and a certain kernel version was incompatible with Hyper-V in such a way that the pf state cleanup timer *would never trigger*; all the tens of thousands of UDP states that ordinary DNS requests create were essentially permanent – their 120-second expiry just wouldn't count down. (Had a nightly reboot cronjob to flush them out.)

Comment: Can you recommend a tool to quickly create X amount of TCP/UDP connections for getting an approximate of my modem's threshold, or is spawning a few thousand of *netcats* in a loop good enough to reproduce this? **Edit**: found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191118/how-to-artificially-open-many-tcp-connection-on-a-host-testing), will test.